# convert coordinates from container's coordinate space to child one

Tags: android, coordinates, touches

I have container which handles all touches and traverse(when necessary)some of the events to its child by calling onTouch which is implemented by child view.The problem is container receives touches in its own coordinate system and child have to translate it to child's CS.Here is container's code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
//handle some gestures
    ....
    //traverse motion event so container's children can handle it
    if(numFingers==1)
        content.onTouch(content,event);
    return true;
}
```

child's code:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //get child's tranformation
    Matrix m=this.getMatrix();
    float[] coords=new float[2];
    //get touch coords
    coords[0]=event.getX();
    coords[1]=event.getY();
    //translate it to child's coordinates
    m.mapPoints(coords);
    PointF p =new PointF(coords[0],coords[1]);
    Piece piece=getPieceUnderPoint(p);
    if (piece!=null)
        Log.d("game field3",piece.i+","+piece.j);
    return true;
}
```

I can see my coordinates is translated incorrectly by drawing rectangle on child's canvas around touch point.

Comment: can you post expected coordinates and the observed coordinates

Answer (score 0):

The solution was is that I have to invert transform matrix before applying it to touch coordinates
m.invert(m);